# Urlmanager ignores everything before index.php

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Our website is 
 `http://test.dobrobut.com/` 
I need to redirect all 
 `http://test.dobrobut.com/phpBB3/index.php?anything_here` requests to 404.
So, here is the problem. 
**Urlmanager begins to apply rules for everything after index.php in request.** 
So I can make request like 
`http://test.dobrobut.com/dsfdsf/dsfdsf/dsfdsf/dsf/index.php` 
OR
`http://test.dobrobut.com/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php`
AND it will lead to site/index.

We have:

```
'showScriptName' => false,
'enableStrictParsing' => true,
'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
```

So how can I redirect all requests to `http://test.dobrobut.com/phpBB3/index.php` to 404?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [Yii's URL routing rules](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html) to accomplish this. In your urlManager configuration specify the following:

```
'showScriptName' => false,
'enableStrictParsing' => true,
'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
'rules' => [
    'host' => 'http://test.dobrobut.com',
    'pattern' => 'phpBB3/index.php',
    'route' => 'site/lost',
],
```

The above configuration will route any request that hits:

```
test.dobrobut.com/phpBB3/index.php
```

to the 'lost' action of your site controller. This means you will have to have your site controller set up in the following manner:

```
use yii\web\HttpException;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    // lot's of code and other actions here ..

    public function actionLost()
    {
        throw new HttpException(404, 'Sorry, the requested resource could not be found');
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but result is the same. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure your .htaccess file (within the web root directory) is configured properly for your application? A discussion on the matter can be found here: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/47615-yii-20-basci-app-i-miss-the-htaccess-file/